Way to inject shell script inside multiline script with arguments task in azure devops yaml
I have a deployment script that aims to deploy in a certain environment. The parameter came from variable groups. This is how it looks like now:
          - script: |
              tags=($(echo "$(clusterTags)" | tr ' ' '\n'))
              case "${tags[*]}" in
                *"UAT-BAU"*)
                  sed -i -e 's/\r$//' ./deploy.sh
                  chmod +x ./deploy.sh
                   ./deploy.sh \
                    "$(param1)" \
                    "$(param2)" \
                    "$(param3)" \
                    "$(param4)" \
                    "$(param5)" \
                    "$(param6)" \
                    "$(param7)" \
                  ;;
                *"BAU"*)
                  if [[ ! " ${tags[*]} " =~ " HOTFIX " ]]; then
                    echo 'Deploying to UAT-BAU'
                  sed -i -e 's/\r$//' ./deploy.sh
                  chmod +x ./deploy.sh
                   ./deploy.sh \
                    "$(param1)" \
                    "$(param2)" \
                    "$(param3)" \
                    "$(param4)" \
                    "$(param5)" \
                    "$(param6)" \
                    "$(param7)" \
                  else
                    echo "##[warning]Skipping UAT-BAU deployment"
                  fi
                  ;;
                *)
                  echo "##[warning]Skipping UAT-BAU deployment"
                  ;;
              esac

I observed that the scripts are duplicated so I plan to import / inject a shell script from a different directory into the main script. My problem is that it cannot recognize variables being passed and it encountered permission issue.
Is it possible to split the shell script with parameters into another file?

Provide more information. Show what detailed attempts you have done, and what errors you got? And which part of the script you want to inject from a separate script file into the main script?

The expression "$(varName)" is only available when directly using the pipeline variables on input fields of pipeline tasks, or directly using in the inline type scripts on the pipeline tasks.
When calling the filePath type scripts from script files, in the script files, you cannot directly use the expression "$(varName)" to reference the pipeline variables. You need to use the corresponding environment variables in the script files.

For generic pipeline variables that are not secret variables, they are automatically decrypted into environment variables. For example, the pipeline variable 'param1' has environment variable "PARAM1" automatically mapped. See "Define variables".

For secret variables, they are not automatically decrypted into environment variables. You need to explicitly map secret variables. See "Set secret variables".



See below example as reference.

The variable group.


Two shell script files, the script myScript01.sh will call the script myScript02.sh.

The myScript01.sh
#!/bin/sh

chmod +x $SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY/scripts/myScript02.sh

# Need to use environment variables to reference the pipeline variables.
sh $SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY/scripts/myScript02.sh "$PARAM1" "$PARAM2"



The myScript02.sh
#!/bin/sh

param1="$1"
param2="$2"

echo "The param1 is not a secret, and its value is:"
echo "$param1"

echo "-----------------------------------------------"

echo "The param2 is not a secret, and its value is:"
echo "$param2"





Call myScript01.sh in pipeline. Need to use the 'env' key to map the secret variable 'param2' into environment variable 'PARAM2'.
variables:
- group: myVarGroup

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Call Script File'
  env:
    PARAM2: $(param2)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo 'Call script file...'
      chmod +x ./scripts/myScript01.sh
      sh ./scripts/myScript01.sh






Have you tried the suggestion shared in my answer above? Is it working for you to run the script? @Dan
